# Capybara / Poltergeist Internals: Running the Server in a Separate Process/Environment

Tags: capybara, poltergeist

I'm attempting to use Capybara and Poltergeist to automate taking screenshots of my Rails application. I already have this *sort of* working, and I've integrated the functionality with  Rails' asset pipeline. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128633/documentation-for-creating-custom-sprockets-processors) for more on that.)

While testing my current setup, however, I've noticed lots of weird issues that seem to be caused by Capybara and my application running in the same process. Is there a way to make Capybara run its server in a separate process, in a different environment?

Comment: Note: I've reposted this question on Capybara's Google Groups page: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ruby-capybara/sW_oH7jg9EA/r94D1yXR_mgJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make Capybara run against an external server by following the directions in the ["Calling remote servers" section](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara#Calling_remote_servers) of the README.  I think your best bet would be to fork an external server yourself before calling Capybara (e.g., in a rake task or a hook in your testing framework) and then treat it as a remote server in Capybara.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Unfortunately I can't use fork since my development environment is on Windows, but I think I get the general idea.

Comment: This solution uses Selenium, so I don't know if it would work with Poltergeist.